# Creating versions for APIs in Tyk carry over version name when going to URL

Tags: api, networking, path, tyk

I am using Tyk as an API gateway for several other APIs I am using. One of the APIs has a URL for staging and a different one for production use. When creating a URL for my API in Tyk, I add a listener path, and specify that I want it stripped from the URL that Tyk will redirect to. For instance

> tyk.url.com with a listener path of /test/ will redirect to
>   api.url.com and not api.url.com/test/

Tyk gives you the ability to add versions to your API as well. Essentially they are simply extra listener paths that fork to more than one URL.

> tyk.url.com/test/ with a version of 'staging' will go to
>   api.staging.url.com
>
> tyk.url.com/test/ with a version of 'production' will go to
>   api.production.url.com

The problem, however, is that in the Tyk UI, they don't allow you to specify you want the version listener path stripped as well. So when you go to staging, for instance, it will successfully go to the correct URL, but will also append your version name to the end of it

> api.staging.url.com/staging/

Have been searching for a way to solve this, but haven't come across any solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Since v1.7 there's an option to strip the version from the path. In your API definition you can alter the "definition" object and add `“strip_path”: true` - you can do this either with an API call or via the "Raw API Definition" at your API Designer.
In v1.8 you'll be able to do this from the UI too.

Comment: Tried adding this to the definition object, as well as to the individual version objects of the Raw API definition JSON. In each case when I update the Raw API definition and reload the page it disappears from the JSON.

Comment: @JBT on what version are you on ? is it On Prem ?

Comment: Oh, I see I'm on 1.6, nvm. Is there no way to strip the path on 1.6??